# Ubuntu installation problem on Asus n46vm

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, tty

My laptop is Asus n46vm with the following specifications:
(Core_i7 ,memory:6 ,hard:1tera)

After installing Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS and restarting at the last stage of installation, the laptop does not enter the login page and goes directly to the tty2 page.

The only operating system installed on the system is Ubuntu.

I will be grateful for your help in solving this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: After restarting system

Comment: No, I removed the flash drive when I saw the message about it.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop? or Ubuntu 22.04.1 Server?   The desktop has a GUI, the server system does not.  Also check your details as you've tagged your system as 20.04, but then say 22.04!  Check & correct your details.

Comment: Yes, ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop

Comment: Can you login to the tty, connect to internet (use USB tethering), and run the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, and restart the computer?